# Назначение мета тегов на страницах сайта в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header, index, meta

Сейчас на всех страницах сайта в head у меня

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
```

Эта фраза по умолчанию для всех страниц сайта на Вордпресс. 
Какой код и где поменять чтобы на страницах категорий и тегов было:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в дирректории `\wp-content\themes\название_вашей_темы` смотрите файл `header.php`. С большой долей вероятности нужный вам код лежит там. Иначе смотрите там же index.php, либо пройдитесь поиском по файлам этой папки, если тема относительно сложная.

Если на всех страницах рубрик и тэгов нужно отключить индексацию, то вилка будет такая

```
if (is_category() || is_tag()) {
    ?><meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /><?php
} else {
    ?><meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /><?php
}
```

Comment: так там в header.php только этот код <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />. Он действует на все страницы. В index.php нет такого ничего. Мне где-то как-то надо сделать условие возможно, что для определённых страниц выводить <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />. Только как и где сделать не знаю. В этом то и мой вопрос

Comment: обновила ответ, добавила вилку

Comment: только что то Вы не так расставили <?php вроде бы

Comment: это ж вставлять прям в <head> вместо <meta name="robots" content="index, follow", правильно?

Comment: а..не..всё правильно, только осталась на всех страницах всё равно <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />ю Возможно у меня is_category() по другому называется..как мне это проверить?

Comment: А для тегов получилось? какой вид имеет url, который вы называете рубрикой?

Comment: coupon-categories/electronics

Comment: для тегов тоже не сработало..url coupon-tags/tag-children/

Comment: это у вас какой-то магазин?

Comment: Всё! сработало такое <?php if (is_archive()) {
    ?><meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /><?php
} else {
    ?><meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /><?php
} ?>

Comment: как раз мне подходит. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Да, общий признак тоже можно использовать. Только учитывайте в будущем, что is_archive() срабатывает на всех типах архивных страниц: теги, рубрики, авторы, даты и т. д.